# pandas - transform 1 dataframe into two dataframe with foreign key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a Dataframe df as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['tom', 28, "tesla", "model s" ], 
    ['nick', 30, "ford", "mustang"], 
    ['juli', 56, "tesla", "model s"]] , 
    columns = ['PersonName', 'PersonAge', "Car", "CarModel"]
)
df.head()

    PersonName  PersonAge   Car CarModel
0   tom     28  tesla   model s
1   nick    30  ford    mustang
2   juli    56  tesla   model s
```

I would like to transform it into two dataframe as follows

```
Person=
PersonName PersonAge CarId
tom        28        1 
nick       30        2
juli       56        1

Cars=
id Car    Model
1  Tesla  Model S
2  Ford   Mustang
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you add a working example so we all have the same code to start with?

Comment: @tdelaney  yes i edit the question with a stupid example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives you what you want.

Use groupby to create Cars dataframe

```
CarsDF = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Car','CarModel']).Car.count())
CarsDF.columns=['v']
CarsDF = CarsDF.reset_index().drop('v', axis=1)
CarsDF.index.name='CarId'
CarsDF
```

Then use merge to add CarId

```
PersonDF = df.merge(CarsDF.reset_index())[['PersonName','PersonAge','CarId']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign columns to new dataframes to create `Person` and `Cars`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     [['tom', 28, "tesla", "model s" ], 
...     ['nick', 30, "ford", "mustang"], 
...     ['juli', 56, "tesla", "model s"]] , 
...     columns = ['PersonName', 'PersonAge', "Car", "CarModel"]
... )
>>> df
  PersonName  PersonAge    Car CarModel
0        tom         28  tesla  model s
1       nick         30   ford  mustang
2       juli         56  tesla  model s
>>> 
>>> Person = df[["PersonName", "PersonAge"]]
>>> Cars = df[["Car", "CarModel"]]
>>> Person
  PersonName  PersonAge
0        tom         28
1       nick         30
2       juli         56
>>> Cars
     Car CarModel
0  tesla  model s
1   ford  mustang
2  tesla  model s
```

Notice that your original dataframe had an index and that index is preserved when creating the new ones. That index can be used as your foreign key. In fact, the indexing part is frequently transparent in pandas. To select a car from the person name, you could

```
>>> Cars[Person["PersonName"] == "nick"]
    Car CarModel
1  ford  mustang
```

If you want to turn the index into its own column you can do so

```
>>> Cars["id"] = Cars.index
>>> Person["CarId"] = Person.index
>>> Person
  PersonName  PersonAge  CarId
0        tom         28      0
1       nick         30      1
2       juli         56      2
>>> Cars
     Car CarModel  id
0  tesla  model s   0
1   ford  mustang   1
2  tesla  model s   2
```

But sticking with operations on the index is generally more convenient.... unless you reset the index, then, you have to go with a different column

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['tom', 28, "tesla", "model s" ],
    ['nick', 30, "ford", "mustang"],
    ['juli', 56, "tesla", "model s"]] ,
    columns = ['PersonName', 'PersonAge', "Car", "CarModel"]
)
df['Comb'] = df['Car'] + "," + df['CarModel']
car_df = pd.DataFrame({'CarId': range(1, len(df['Comb'].unique())+1), 'Comb': df['Comb'].unique()})
car_df = car_df.merge(df[['Comb', 'Car', 'CarModel']], on=['Comb']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Comb']).drop(columns=['Comb'])

df = df.merge(car_df, on=['Car', 'CarModel']).drop(columns=['Comb', 'Car', 'CarModel'])
car_df = car_df.set_index('CarId')
print(df)
print()
print(car_df)
```

Output:

```
  PersonName  PersonAge  CarId
0        tom         28      1
1       juli         56      1
2       nick         30      2

         Car CarModel
CarId                
1      tesla  model s
2       ford  mustang
```